# How can I clear the ArrayList object after put the object in session?

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection, garbage

I am facing problem when I put the data into the ArrayList by

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList.add("one");
arrList.add("two");
arrList.add("three");
```

After that I am going to put List object into the session by

```
session.setAttributes("sessionArray",arrList);
```

And after put the list object into session. I want to clear the existing ArrayList object by

```
arrList.clear();
```

But after that when I am trying to get the ArrayList object from session attributes by

```
ArrayList<String> sessionList = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttributes("sessionArray");
```

It return **null**. Please help me out that How can I clear the ArrayList object after put the object in session?

Comment: Is there any possibility that the `arrayList` set null in somewhere else?

Comment: Is session.getAttributes("sessionArray") null even if arrList.clear(); is commented?

Comment: @Razib Yes after put the the arraylist object in the session. I am going to set it null also. But I want it to clear.

Comment: @ abj1305 When i commented the arrList.clear() then it working fine.

Comment: When `arrList.clear()` has an impact on the subsequent behavior of `session`, it implies that it keeps a reference to the list object when you call `setAttributes`. Apparently, it returns `null` when the list is empty. Which suggests, that you shouldn’t modify the list after passing it to `setAttributes`.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you mean by "session"?

Comment: @ Håkan HttpSession object in Java

Comment: What servlet engine are you using? I assume Tomcat, but what version specifically?

Comment: Rather than doing arrList.clear(); why dont you do arrList = new ArrayList<>()? It will stop you modifying the object which you added to the session, and it effectively clears (creates a new array list)? Would that not work?

Comment: @Speakjava Tomcat 7 I use. But I don't think its any issues from the server side.

Comment: Is it possible to create a simple reproducer (i.e. code that just sets the attribute, etc)? If you can post this it will be easier to figure out what is going on.